# url() function for HTML background

Tags: html, css

```
div {  background:url(smiley.gif) top left no-repeat }
```

What is this `url()`? I can't find documentation online.

(See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your example `url` is the url of the image that will be used as the background for the `div` tag.

MDN has a decent explanation of it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/uri

MDN is usually more up-to-date than W3Schools.

Answer (score 2):

It's the URL of the background image.

For example, lets say you've your images stored at `/images` and you've a background image called `background.png` located at `/images/background.png`, then you do:

```
background-image: url('/images/background.png');
```

Comment: Is there official documentation somewhere?

Comment: A thing to remember: Relative URLs, if used, are relative to the URL of the stylesheet (not to the URL of the web page). So we might end up using `url(../images/background.png)` if style directory (where *.css files are kept) is stored in parallel to the `images` directory.

Answer (score 0):

the background of the div will be image from file called smiley.gif
you should have a file called smiley.gif at the same directory of your html file

Answer (score 0):

Here is the page that mentions url: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp  Other than that, url is simply a url string pointing to the image.

Answer (score 0):

it's not HTML, yes CSS(Cascading Style Sheets).
the `url ()` function set the background image for an element.